# Binding functions to mouse

Tags: mouse, shortcut-keys

I'm pretty much brand new to Ubuntu/Linux (using Ubuntu 16.04) and have been having a terrible time trying to set up some new bindings for my mouse (Logitech MX Revolution). After two afternoons of trying to get this to work my patience is running thin.

What I'm trying to do is simply bind a mute function to one of the extra buttons on my mouse.

I've looked at many guides already but all of them are either missing key information or are written for intermediate/advanced users who already know the OS well.

I've used xinput test to determine that the mouse I would like to bind keys for is using the ID of 13 and the button that I would like to map is 225.

Now my keyboard (MX5500) has a mute button that does work, so using xinput it gave me a button number of 121.  However I also used xbindkeys -k to determine the raw keycodes for that working keyboard mute button is m:0x10 + c:121 / Mod2 + XF86AudioMute.

I've created the ~/.xbindkeysrc in the home directory and have installed xautomation but this is where I get lost.  From what I'm understanding I am to add some like:

```
#MMMute
"xte 'm:0x10 + c:121'"
  b:225 + Release
```

But it's not working and I've tried quite a few combinations between the raw keycodes, Mod2 + XF86AudioMute, 121, etc etc etc. Clearly I have no idea what I'm doing and any help at all would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I'm back, with a different account and an answer to my own question!

So maybe you're having trouble binding keyboard functions to your extra mouse buttons like I was...  And maybe things just aren't working out. Well, I found an easy way to do what I wanted with minimal effort!

Is it the "correct" way to do this? Don't know, don't care.  All I know is that it works the way I'd like it to.

Let's assume we already know the function we would like to bind; in this case it is `XF86AudioMute`

First off we're going to need xdotool.  If you don't have it then open up your terminal and enter:

```
sudo apt install xdotool
```

Now open System Settings -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts

At the bottom under Custom Shortcuts and click the + to add a new shortcut.  Name it whatever you'd like; in my case it's listed as MagicalMiddleMouseMute. The command we will add is:

```
xdotool key XF86AudioMute
```

Once that is applied, simply click the 'Disabled' tag and then specify what button you would like to bind by clicking it.  Voilà, we now have a mute toggle function bound to the extra middle mouse-search button, as well as the original keyboard mute button.